# JQuery Modifying CSS class for print.css file not taking effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, print-css

I have a page with two different print buttons and two types of div tags:

```
<button onclick="window.print()">Print Full</button>
<button onclick="PrintPartial()">Print Partial</button>

<div class="not-partial">
    Div Content Here should print for "Print Full" but not for "Print Partial" 
</div>

<div class="no-print">
    This content shouldn't print on either
<div>
```

I have the following in my print.css file

```
.no-print { display: none; }
```

And below is my PrintPartial() function

```
function PrintPartial() {
    var notPartial = $(".not-partial");
    notPartial.addClass("no-print");
    window.print();
    notPartial.removeClass("no-print");
}
```

The "Print Full" button works just fine and prints according to my print.css file. The div that is hard coded with the "no-print" class correctly does not print.

However the "Print Partial" button print out is exactly the same as the print full button.

When I run my debugger and step into my PrintPartial() function I can inspect the elements and the "no-print" class is getting added to the correct elements. It calls window.print() which opens the print dialog and it removes the "no-print" class from the elements stored in the notPartial variable.

My only thought is the JQuery select and addClass is running asynchronously and its calling print before the class has changed?  If so how do I make sure the window.print isn't called until after the addClass is complete.

I tried running it without the removeClass step and got the same results so I know its not my issue, or at least its not my ONLY issue.

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to correct it?

Thanks,
    Scott

UPDATE:  The above code works fine as Pabs123 pointed out. I had an issue where a different piece of css (not included in this post) is causing the display property to be changed back.

Thanks

Comment: looks fine http://codepen.io/pabs123/pen/YNWEyO only thing I can think of is that there is other css acting on that element or there is some other external css not show here

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I just realized I have another piece of css on my page that is overriding the display:none.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, The code I posted here works as intended.  As Pabs123 suggested in his/her comment, I had other conflicting css that was not included with the post, that was changing the display style back from display: none.  So as posted this wasn't really a good question. Sorry.

Thanks for your help.